# uWSGI NOT working with .ini file

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

*uWSGI NOT working with .ini file but works directly from command line.*

For this project, I'm using `Python` with `Django`, `NGinX` and `uWSGI`.
When running the server configuration with parameters directly in the command line, it works but does not work when using the .ini file.

In my `NGinX` configuration, I have this uwsgi_pass command:

```
uwsgi --socket ifbAMPdatabase/ifbAMPdatabase.sock --module ifbAMPdatabase.wsgi  --chmod-socket=666
```

**.ini file:**

```
[uwsgi]
project = ifbAMPdatabase
base = /home/ampdbvenv/ifbAMPdb

home = %(base)/pyVenvIFBAMPDB/
chdir = %(base)/%(project)/
#module = %(base)/%(project).wsgi
module = %(project).wsgi:application
wsgi-file = %(base)/%(project)/wsgi.py

master = true
processes = 4

socket = %(base)/%(project)/%(project).sock
chmod-socket = 666
vacuum = true

; plugins=python

enable-threads = true
uid = www-data
gid = www-data
log-date = true
```

**OBS:**

Some of these parameters I have added just for testing, but they didn't change a thing (*it wasn't working with a simple .ini file like in the documentaton*).

**nginx site file:**

```
    location / {
    uwsgi_pass  django;
    include     /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I'm probably facing something similar.

Comment: @Ajoy not really. I decided to leave uWSGI for Gunicorn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my project, uwsgi run in docker container

`socket = :8000` not work

but, change to

`http-socket = :8000` it work

hope that will be helpful

Comment: You saved my life. In All tutorials are socket instead of http-socket. Only http-socket works